# Find $\nabla (\vert \overrightarrow r \rvert^2)$

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

**Extra background info:**

$\overrightarrow r$ is the vector from the source point ($\overrightarrow a$) to the field point ($\overrightarrow b$).

$\overrightarrow a=(x',y',z')$

$\overrightarrow b=(x,y,z)$

[Screenshot of the problem in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOQca.jpg)

---

I'm having trouble with just one part. I don't know how to take the derivative of each component.

Given that $\vert \overrightarrow r \rvert=\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}$, $\vert \overrightarrow r \rvert ^2$ = $(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2$.

$\nabla (\vert \overrightarrow r \rvert ^2)= \hat x \frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x}+\hat y \frac{\partial r^2}{\partial y}+\hat z \frac{\partial r^2}{\partial z}$

But here is where I'm stuck. When we have $x-x'$, how do I take the derivative of this? Do I only take the derivative the first $x$ because the denominator of the operator says $x$ and not $x'$?

Comment: $x'$ is a constant, so the derivative with respect to $x$ is zero.

Comment: Technically they are both constants. I've edited my question to include this missing piece of info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x} &= 2(x-x')
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
\nabla (r^2) &= 2 \,[ \ \hat x (x-x')+\hat y (y-y')+\hat z(z-z') \ ]\\
&=2(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})
\end{align*}

According to the screen shot of the problem you have 
$$
\nabla (r^2) = 2 \mathbf{r}
$$

Comment: Does this still hold given the extra info I've provided, where $r$ is just the vector between 2 points?

Comment: Well $x$ can't be constant. You are taking the derivative with respect to $x$. It means it is a variable. Here your vector $a$ should be fixed and $b$ should be a variable. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to take the derivative of a constant distance.

Comment: I think it is, per the question. Here is a screenshot of the original question: http://imgur.com/a/IP6lc

Comment: In that image it says only $(x',y',z')$ is fixed. And $\mathbf{r} = (x,y,z) - (x',y',z')$.

Comment: You $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector that changes when $(x,y,z)$ changes.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh ok so the second point is not fixed. Wait but my professor was saying that irl scientists measure the field strength by placing a charge inside a field, then measuring the field strength at another location called the field point. By what he said, it implies that both points are fixed, no?

Comment: You can measure the distance between two fixed points, that is okay. However sometimes you deal with a function that depends on a point that is  kind of unknown. In this problem your function $\mathbf{r}$ is like that. For example, sometimes you calculate $3^2$, but sometimes you deal with a function $x^2$ where $x$ is unknown.